# Windows 7 & now windows 8 BSOD Internal_power_error

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, bsod

Recently I purchased a Asrock 990fx Extreme9 and FX-3970, both of these parts are used but I was assured that they were in working order.

I have gone through 3 days of trouble shooting issues with these parts and have now moved from windows 7 to 8 to see if it makes any difference in terms of driver versions etc but I am now getting a new BSOD with the error Internal_Power_Error.

Can someone who is experienced with dump files take a look at mine and let me know what they think is causing it, there are 2 things in the dump file "ntoskrnl.exe" and "storport.sys" that are last on the dump but other have said that these are usually not the cause of the BSOD so I am not sure what could be.

Any help would be really appreciated as I have spend days on this now and feel like I am getting no where.

[Dropbox link to 4 dmp files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2u1duax11csci4m/032315-74116-01.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dump shows that the AMD AHCI driver causes the issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR (a0)
The power policy manager experienced a fatal error.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000613, A driver has attempted to complete a request when no such
    outstanding request is pending.
Arg2: fffffa8007bb5c60, POP_FX_DEVICE device
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Component index
Arg4: 0000000000000001, Report device powered on

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for amdxata.sys

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

BIOS_DATE:  06/04/2014

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  990FX Extreme9

BASEBOARD_VERSION:                        

BUGCHECK_P1: 613

BUGCHECK_P2: fffffa8007bb5c60

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 1

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 1127

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 15

CPU_MODEL: 2

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA0

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10041.3 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff803fcf9a73c to fffff803fce84040

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!PopFxBugCheck
02 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
03 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
04 storport!StorPortUnitPoFxD0Completion
05 storport!RaidUnitProcessSetDevicePowerIrpComplete
06 storport!RaidUnitProcessSetDevicePowerIrp
07 storport!RaidUnitSetDevicePowerIrp
08 storport!RaidUnitSetPowerIrp
09 storport!RaUnitPowerIrp
0a storport!RaDriverPowerIrp
0b amdxata!FilterSCSI
0c 0x0
0d 0x0
0e 0x0
0f 0x0
10 0x0
11 0x0
12 CLASSPNP!ClasspPowerUpCompletion
13 nt!IopfCompleteRequest
14 storport!RaidCompleteRequestEx
15 storport!RaUnitScsiIrp
16 storport!RaDriverScsiIrp
17 amdxata!_GSHandlerCheckCommon
18 0x0
19 0x0
1a 0x0
1b 0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  amdxata.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4accf643

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  9f

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xA0_amdxata!FilterSCSI

BUCKET_ID:  0xA0_amdxata!FilterSCSI

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xA0_amdxata!FilterSCSI

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xa0_amdxata!filterscsi


fffff880`0154f000 fffff880`0155a000   amdxata  M (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\blue9600\amdxata.pdb\C1973DADED5A407F9EE44887872773D31\amdxata.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: amdxata.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\amdxata.sys
    Image name: amdxata.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Oct 07 22:12:51 2009 (4ACCF643)
```

The driver is from 2009. [Update the driver to the latest version from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows+8.1+-+64#2).

Comment: Thanks I will mark as correct a friend took a look and said the same thing, oddly enough I used the all in one installer from AMD which told me it was up to date I will have a crack at it tonight when I get home thanks!

Comment: also try the Microsoft standard driver if the AMD one causes issues.

Comment: I am downloading those drivers now, noticed that AHCI was turned on in Bios but not in windows so have enabled that in the registry as well to see if that helps.

Comment: OK well just to finish this one off, I went back to IDE mode because if I tried at all to install these drivers it would BSOD, it should be noted I haven't bothered trying to re-install until I re-install windows completely on a new SSD, I did replace my PSU and since then the computer has been faster and far more stable. Thanks again for pointing out the problem.